# raise SerializationError

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch, scrapy

i'm using elasticsearch to save scrapy Data but 
when i run my code i get this error:

raise SerializationError(data, e)

elasticsearch.exceptions.SerializationError: ({'real_estate_ID': [],

but it function with the other items i get a problem only with the item : real_estate_ID

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import scrapy
from adds.items import AddsItem
import stomp
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, helpers

class addsSpider(scrapy.Spider):

   name = "adds"

custom_settings = {
    'DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES': {
        'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None,
        'scrapy_fake_useragent.middleware.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 400,
    }
}
allowed_domains = ["www.seloger.com"]
start_urls = ['https://www.seloger.com/list.htm? 
tri=initial&idtypebien=2,1&idtt=2,5&naturebien=1,2,4&ci=750115']

   es = Elasticsearch('localhost:9200',use_ssl=False,verify_certs=True)

def parse(self, response):
    es = Elasticsearch()
    es.indices.create(index="first_index", ignore=400)
    conn = stomp.Connection()
    conn.start()
    conn.connect('admin', 'password', wait=True)
    items = AddsItem()
    items['real_estate_ID'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="c-pa-list c-pa- 
    sl c-pa-gold cartouche "]//@id').extract()
    items['real_estate_URL'] = response.xpath('//a[@class="c-pa-link 
    link_AB"]//@href').extract()
    items['real_estate_sale_price'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="h-fi- 
    pulse annonce__detail__sauvegarde"]//@data-prix').extract()
    items['real_estate_category'] = response.xpath('//a[@class="c-pa-link 
    link_AB"]//@title').extract()
    for item in items['real_estate_URL']:
       conn.send(body=item, destination='/queue/scrapy.seloger.ads.queue', 
    persistent='false')
    yield items

    nextpageurl = response.xpath('//a[@class="pagination-next"]/@href')

    if nextpageurl:
        # If we've found a pattern which matches
        path = nextpageurl.extract_first()
        nextpage = response.urljoin(path)
        print("Found url: {}".format(nextpage))  # Write a debug statement
        yield scrapy.Request(nextpage, callback=self.parse)  

    es.index(index="urls", doc_type="Ads_url", id=1, body=items)

    res = es.get(index="urls", doc_type="Ads_url", id=1)
```

Comment: Is that the whole error message? Does your serializer require a single string value in the `real_estate_ID` field? What happens when you manually set it to the empty string `""`? And can you confirm that your XPath is correct for that field?

Comment: Or maybe it requires an int?

Comment: yeah it's the whole error message

Comment: and about the real_estate_ID it's something like this : idannonce-123791397

Comment: Are you expecting a single value or a list? When I run your XPath I get a list of IDs. In other words, are you trying to add all the IDs into one `AddsItem` or is your intention you add a `AddsItem` for every item on the page?

Comment: when i get the result i get the same problem with it    TypeError("Unable to serialize {'real_estate_ID': ['annonce-141069693-262350'

Comment: It looks like you are scraping all the fields into a single `AddsItem`. Can you confirm if that is really what you want to do, or if you really want to have a separate `AddsItem` for each item on the page?

Comment: into a single one

Comment: Can you show a working example of your ES code without any Scrapy code? Like a valid example of `items`. Then we can compare that with what Scrapy returns.

Comment: the ES works without any problem but what i want to know when you run this code you get the result without this problem?

Comment: I didn't run the exact code, because I don't have ES set up. I only checked the XPaths. When I strip out all the ES code I end up with 1 item with multiple values per field. If you can show me a working example based on this [official example](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/#example-usage) then I can investigate further. I still think the problem is that you actually need *multiple* items with single-valued fields.

Comment: i don't think that it's a problem of items